# Image Background Overflow Issues

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a couple of PNG images that I am positioning between sections, which has went well, but when I have arrived at the footer, my hero video at the back comes through when I apply a 'top' property.

I've tried a few things such as applying width/height then overflow: hidden, nothing seems to be working. It works fine as a CSS background but it means I can't edit the image within the section, at least I don't think I can.

Basically I am just looking for the image to be pushed down beyond the footer, without displaying my hero video behind it.

I'm quite new to this so any helpful feedback or advice would be great!

HTML

```
<footer>
 <img class="leaf-left" src="resources/img/leafgroup-left.png">

        <!-- ~~~ insert section img -->


        <div class="row">
           <div class="cta-text animated shake">
            <ul class="footer-nav">

                <h2>Upcoming project? Get in Touch.</h2>
            </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.footer-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.leaf-left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    left: 80%;
    top: 900%;
}
```

[image: top: 890%]

[image: top: 900%]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but rather than using `top: 900%;`, can't you use the `bottom` property with a negative value? And the footer element doesn't have an `overflow: hidden` property in your code

Comment: Yeah thats a better idea, thanks. It did earlier but didn't make any difference so has since been removed. I want the PNG to go beyond the footer without expanding it downwards.

Comment: Actually I take the `bottom` comment back. Realized that top is more suitable when I posted my answer.

Comment: The bottom property is actually better now I've sorted the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the parent. I made a minimalist example below:

```css
footer {
    background-color: #9a9a9a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative; /* This is important */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-simulation {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="image-simulation"></div>
</footer>
```